# copy files to another location based on registry information

Tags: installshield

I need to copy a plugin files to the currently installed location of adobe reader. From my research I know that this data is in the registry but how can I do this copy via installsield  2013. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path is in the registry, you can use System Search /AppSearch to locate the value  from the registry, store it in a property in the installer and then use that property as the basis for the directory table entry that some components in your installer will use.

Comment: Can you give some screen shots. I'm a total noob wrt to installshield.